# Compatibility and Performance Visual Studio 2012 on Windows XP

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-xp, visual-studio-2012

I need to install Visual Studio 2012 on a Windows XP system. I already have installed Visual Studio 2010 (Framework 4) on that machine. Is there any compatibility or performance issue regarding that?

Comment: To my knowledge, VS2012 [doesn't support Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compatibility).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, it's not compatible with WinXP: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compatibility

Comment: In case someone needs to know, you can still write applications in VS2012 that target XP (although obviously VS must be installed on another PC), but without remote debugging support.